# sudo -u user "whoami" works but not other commands

Tags: sudo, centos-7

When I run the following it works:

```
sudo -u apache 'whoami'
```

But when I run this, it says command not found:

```
sudo -u apache 'ls -al ~/.ssh'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` sees the entire `ls -al ~/.ssh` string as one argument and runs it as one, as if the `apache` user invoked

```
'ls -al ~/.ssh'
```

And this doesn't work because there is no tool named literally `ls -al ~/.ssh` as a whole. Your command should be more like

```
sudo -u apache ls -al ~/.ssh
```

Note this will expand `~` before `sudo` even starts, in the context of your actual user. This, on the other hand:

```
sudo -u apache ls -al ~apache/.ssh
```

may be what you really want.